# How can I display an image from the web in a WinJS app

Tags: html, winjs

A Windows Store App in HTML/Javascript, I have following HTML code:

`<img src="http://server/website/images/image.png" />`

The image does not display, I get an X like image when an image is not found.

I have verified my url.

According to this article you can use HTTP URIs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx

What can be the issue?

Comment: Does your app have the Internet (Client) capability declared? If not, you won't be able to access http: URIs in any way, including image references.

Comment: Yes it does. I also tried to declare Internet (Client & Server) capability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display images from an intranet source to following must be selected in the app manifest capabilities section:

- Enterprise Authentication
- Private Networks (Client & Server)